# Tomcat showing old pages

Tags: tomcat

I have a Tomcat installation that keeps showing old pages (and old JS files). What I tried so far is:

1. Stopped Tomcat,
2. Deployed my new files under `webapps`,
3. Deleted all folders and their contents under `...work/Catalina/localhost`,
4. Re-start Tomcat.

(by the way, I'm using `$CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh` and `$CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh` to start and stop.

The interesting thing is that I searched (Linux command) for the file that appears to be outdated (a JS file) and didn't find it.

Of course, also tried to flush my browser's history. Nothing appears to be working and I'm still getting the wrong file (in Chrome, I checked the sources and I can see an old version of the JS file).

Answer (score 0):

Two more places make sense to look at:

- $CATALINA_HOME/temp (especially when you're using a JS-minifier. If so, also check whereever it might cache its own data)
- Any proxy that is between your browser and your server. Quick test: If `http://www.example.com/some-file.js` is old&stale, request `http://www.example.com/some-file.js?a` to bypass any possibility for caches to stay in the line.

Comment: Thank you @OlafKock for your response. The first point revealed a single file named something like `safetodelete.abc` which was empty. After deleting it, I'm still getting the old files. The configuration is as follows: I have to computers in the same network (say 10.0.0.*) so I don't see where a proxy could be.

Comment: Did you try the second approach or did you just rule out proxies?

Comment: Second option because I'm not sure how to perform it. Should I use the same URL to the `index.html` but, instead, deploy the path to a specific JS that I'm getting an old version? For instance, if the first URL would be: `http://MyWeb.com/index.html` the test should be: `http://MyWeb.com/myllibs/js/controllers/mycontroller.js?a`. Sorry for the silly question, but I'm quite new in this.

Comment: well, you state that your server is serving some stale resource - most likely the one that you name as 'http://MyWeb.com/myllibs/js/controllers/mycontroller.js'. So yes, append any http-parameter to that URL and check if it's still stale. If it isn't, you know that something along the way is caching it.